# SQL Where exists use value else use another

Tags: sql

I have a table where I want to join to bring through an i.d, straight forward enough but I only want to bring through values that are 'live' (referenced by a 1 in the flag column below). On the latest year no values are live yet but I need these values brought through too. It might be easier to explain in an example.

Joining Table:

```
Company     Year      Product    ID     Flag
A           2019       X         100     0
A           2019       X         101     1
A           2019       Y         102     1
A           2019       Y         103     0
A           2019       Y         104     0
A           2020       X         105     1
A           2020       Y         106     0
A           2020       Y         107     1
A           2020       Y         108     0 
A           2020       Z         109     1
A           2021       X         110     0
A           2021       Y         111     0
A           2021       Y         112     0
A           2021       Y         113     0 
A           2021       Z         114     0
```

I need to bring through those values that have a 1 in the Flag column and then all values with a year of 2021 (when 2021 begins the values in the flag column for 2021 will swap to zeroes and 1s, with the need to only bring through the rows with a 1 in the flag column, again).

The need to bring through next years values will reoccur at the end of every year so the idea is to future proof this from further changes so adding a when year =2021 is not an option.

The original table has the company, year and product so when I join it will be on these three fields.

Any thoughts, let me know

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: And tag with the datbase youa re using.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where flag = 1 or year = extract(year from current_date)
```

This brings rows where `flag` has value `1` or where `year` is the current year.

Note that this uses standard date functions `extract()` and `current_date` - not all databases support this syntax, but they all have equivalent.

Comment: I really like the `extract` method!